# Dask scatter broadcast a list

Tags: broadcast, dask, dask-distributed

what is the appropriate way to **scatter broadcast** a list using Dask disitributed?

case 1 - wrapping the list:

```
[future_list] = client.scatter([my_list], broadcast=True)
```

case 2 - not wrapping the list:

```
future_list = client.scatter(my_list, broadcast=True)
```

In the Dask documentation I have seen both examples: [1. wrapping (see bottom example)](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=scatter#distributed.client.Client.scatter) and [2. not wrapping](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/locality.html?highlight=scatter#user-control). In my experience case 1 is the best approach, in case 2 constructing the Dask graph (large in my use case) takes a lot longer.

What could explain the difference in graph construction time? Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call scatter with a `list` then Dask will assume that each element of that list should be scattered independently.

```
a, b, c = client.scatter([1, 2, 3], ...)
```

If you don't want this, if you actually just want your list to be moved around as a single piece of data, then you should wrap it in another list

```
[future] = client.scatter([[1, 2, 3]], ...)
```

Comment: Is this also the case with `broadcast=True`?

Comment: Yes. `broadcast` is not about how the variables are handled, but to control whether the data is replicated to all your workers.